# Java jdbc update can't work

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi i am new to programming , i have recently stumbled across this logic error which i couldn't solve. When i click update in the UI , console display success is false.May i know how can i increment executeUpdate to 1?. Thanks in advance

```
public static boolean updateStaff(Staff staff) {
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery; 
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    //step 1 - establish connection to database
    db.getConnection();     

    //step 2 - declare the SQL statement
    dbQuery = "UPDATE staff SET staffID = ?, staffName = ?, staffPassword= ?, staffNRIC = ?, staffGender = ?, staffContactNo = ?, staffEmail = ?, dob = ?, department = ? WHERE id = ?";
    pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

    //step 3 - to update record using executeUpdate method
    try {
        pstmt.setString(1, staff.getStaffID());
        pstmt.setString(2, staff.getStaffName());
        pstmt.setString(3, staff.getStaffPassword());
        pstmt.setString(4, staff.getStaffNRIC());
        pstmt.setString(5, staff.getStaffGender());
        pstmt.setInt(6, staff.getStaffContactNo());
        pstmt.setString(7, staff.getStaffEmail());
        pstmt.setString(8, staff.getDOB());
        pstmt.setString(9, staff.getDepartment());
        pstmt.setInt(10,staff.getId());

        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1)
            success = true;
            System.out.println("success" + success);
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(success);
    //step 4 - close connection
    db.terminate();

    return success;     
}
```

below is the UI

```
    private void actionPerformedUpdate(){
        int contact = 0;

        if (validateInput()) {
            contact = Integer.parseInt(txtStaffContact.getText());
            // create an object of expenses based on the input values
            Staff e1 = new Staff(txtStaffID.getText(), txtStaffName.getText(),txtStaffNRIC.getText(), txtStaffGender.getText(), contact , txtStaffEmail.getText() , txtStaffDOB.getText() , txtStaffDepartment.getText(),txtStaffPassword.getText());

            // insert to database and check return value
            if (StaffDA.updateStaff(e1) == true) {
            //if(StaffController.createStaff(e1)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HMSFrame,
                        "Record created successfully", "Alert",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                // reset text field for next record.


            } else if(StaffDA.updateStaff(e1) == false){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HMSFrame,
                        "Database Error. Record not created.", "Alert",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean validateInput() {
        boolean result = false;
        String msg = "";
        int msgType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
        // retrieve the user input from the text box/area provided
        String staffID = txtStaffID.getText();
        String staffName = txtStaffName.getText();
        String staffNRIC = txtStaffNRIC.getText();
        String staffGender = txtStaffGender.getText();
        String StaffContactNo = txtStaffContact.getText();
        String staffEmail = txtStaffEmail.getText();
        String dob = txtStaffDOB.getText();
        String department = txtStaffDepartment.getText();


        if (staffName.length() == 0)
            msg += "Please enter staff''s Full Name.\n";

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(StaffContactNo); // convert to Integer for time 
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if (StaffContactNo.length() > 8)        
            msg += "Plese enter hours in 24 hour clock format.\n";
        }



        if (msg.length() == 0)
            result = true;
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HMSFrame, msg, "Alert", msgType);
        return result;


}
```

Comment: No stacktrace on the console?

Comment: Could it be that the result returned by pstmt.executeUpdate() be greater than 1?

Comment: Are you sure the record for update exist? Check with debug the ID is OK

Comment: How do i know if the record for update existed? for the ID part , my retrieve is retrieve by ID and its working.I can retrieve the data that i selected from JTable and display in this update panel.